# ActivityNotFound exception thrown for PreferenceActivity listed in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a Preference screen to my app.

**Preferences.java:**

```
 public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
    }
 }
```

**preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <PreferenceCategory
    android:title="General Settings">
    <RingtonePreference
        android:name="Ringtone"
        android:summary="Select a Ringtone for recieved messages"
        android:title="Rington"
        android:key="ringtonPref" />
  </PreferenceCategory>
  <PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Account Settings">
        <Preference
            android:title="Sign Out"
            android:summary="Sign out of current account"
            androidKey="signOut" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="steamanywhere.com"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                 android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".SteamAnywhere"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>

        <acitivity android:name="steamanywhere.com.Preferences" >
        </acitivity>    
        <activity android:name=".StartupScreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".WebEventListener" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

The Preferences activity is started in SteamAnywhere.java with the following code:

```
Intent preferenceIntent = new Intent(this, steamanywhere.com.Preferences.class);
startActivity(preferenceIntent);
```

On `startActivity(preferenceIntent);` I get the following exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {steamanywhere.com/steamanywhere.com.Preferences}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

But it is declared.. Any ideas?

I've looked through many similar questions but none of the answers work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer may be in your xml

```
<acitivity android:name="steamanywhere.com.Preferences" >
</acitivity>
```

You've spelt `activity` wrong.

```
<activity android:name="steamanywhere.com.Preferences" >
</activity>
```

Also, why do you not just say?

```
<activity android:name=".Preferences" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Its always the stupidest things.. Been banging my head against a wall for over an hour. Thank you that worked. I originally had it as just ".Preferences" but another similar question suggested fully qualifying it and I hadn't changed it back yet.

Comment: ha, no worries Khalos. Glad I could help. ;)