# How to resolve issue of "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity" ActivityNotFoundException in google signin integration

Tags: android, google-signin

I have integrated google signin in android app but when run app I getting exception like:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
> activity class
> {com.example/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity};
>
> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Can you please tell how I declare SignInHubActivity in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Declaring

Comment: You can add it like any other activity - <activity android:name=".SignInHubActivity" android:label = ..../>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity Declaration in AndroidManifest.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122386/activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Really I was doing very silly mistake. 
I just declare activity see below...

```
<activity
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
```

Now my problem solved. Google signin working fine.... Thank you

Comment: I got exactly the same problem today, but there should be a better solution. `startActivityForResult()` should not reqire to declare every activity it starts, because often it is not known in advance. I am using Eclipse but when I tried AndroidStudion there were not need to add anything in the manifest. What IDE are you using? I wonder how to configure Eclipse project correctly.

Comment: @hharry_tech can you help me with signin? I am also using eclipse. and always get error like" signin_required."

Comment: You would need a **zero argument constructor** in your SignInHubActivity in order to avoid a crash.

Comment: Thank you so much  you wouldn't believe how long this held me up

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Eclipse with ADT? (Android Development Tools plugin). Have you followed instructions here to set up Google Play services SDK?
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

If you set it up correctly, I believe SignInHubActivity definition will be automatically merged into your manifest from Google Play services SDK and you don't need to explicitly declare it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem. Finally I solved it. It is caused by "Manuel Migration to AndroidX". I've followed instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FZ_eUIsLTg

and problem solved.

the key factor is upgrading the compileSdkVersion to the newest. and it is recommended to make all versions up-to-date in files *build.gradle, app/build.gradle, pubspec.yaml*.

then Android Studio manages migration successfuly, and ActivityNotFoundException problem is solved.

And final reminder for Turkish guys.
You should change these keywords (in app/build.gradle) as following:

testImplementation -> **testİmplementation**

androidTestImplementation -> **androidTestİmplementation**