# The activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml

I am getting an error which reads **The activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml**

[image: Screenshot of the error]

What is the problem here?

Comment: From the screenshot, because the activity is red, I would guess you have it in the wrong package. Can you share a screenshot of your main activity?

Comment: is there a whitespace before ".MainActivity" ? It looks like there is one before the point(.)...

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.

Comment: Can you please put the log and your AndroidManifest.xml code here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740240/no-idea-annotations-attached-to-the-jdk-1-8-c-some-issues-will-not-be-fo
this is how it worked for me.

Comment: answer by Levi Rizki Saputra helped me out
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740240/no-idea-annotations-attached-to-the-jdk-1-8-c-some-issues-will-not-be-fo>

Answer (score 18):

I got this error when moving a lot of files, to fix just resync your gradle files.

*File->Sync Project with Gradle Files*

Comment: This worked for me. anyway, frustrating bugs of android studio. the bug still can happen in AS 4.0.1. The confusing part of the bug is that it can find the activity for choosing the activity, but then just wont build/run it for device as it thinks that there's no activity, but in the other window it can clearly scan and see it.

Answer (score 12):

Try to go to File->Invalidate Caches / Restart and choose invalidate and restart ,it worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes when moving or renaming files, you can have broken XML files. My case that the ic_launcher.xml was corrupt. I regenerated that and worked just fine.

Check every XML in your proyect.

Answer (score 4):

You are most likely just missing the below from your `AndroidManifest`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Here is a full example of an `AndroidManifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pejner.myapplication">

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I used your code and the error still persists. Plz tell if you need any other file code.

Comment: Requires:
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

Comment: I hate that you can't shift+enter in comments :'(

Answer (score 3):

this happened for me when my laptop suddenly shut down when working with project. if you see your activity declaration in your manifest, do not open any xml files. they maybe broken and corrupt after opening files.
so do these steps:

1. delete all .iml files from your project
2. go to Files => invalidate cache / Restart
3. Rebuild your project gradle
4. finally if problem still exists, go to Files => Sync project with gradle files

https://stacklearn.ir

Answer (score 1):

This can be only two reason,

the bold one, missing extend statement

```
class MainActvity extends AppCompatActivity
```

or

you are using a wrong package name to register your activity so just in this case use ALT+Space then studio will show the options itself.

Answer (score 1):

All of my XML file were cut in half for some reason, I'm not sure when it happened (I use Git VCS, so maybe that). I had to go through each of them and restore the code.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Got fix from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57656095/2332059

Answer (score 1):

It have three ways to resolve

**1:-**
Go File->Invalidate Caches /  choose invalidate and restart ,it works

**2:-**
If you make `MainActivity` make sure you have `onCreate` method in it and extend with `AppCompatActivity` .

**3:-** And last option sync project with Gradle file

Answer (score 1):

Follow  these steps:

1. File => Invalidate Caches / Restart...
2. Files => Sync project with gradle files

If the steps above don't work, write:

```
com.example.(project name).MainActivity
```

It should work, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those cases the you recently changed the `android:allowBackup` settings, make sure you also set the `tools:replace="android:allowBackup"` in case some of your dependency have it declared in them to override it. I wouldn't know this solution until I manually execute `Gradle > app > cleanbuild > lintFix`

The exact error I received was:

> Error: Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:41:9-36
> is also present at [com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.2.0] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-35 value=(true).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:39:5-254:19 to override.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.YOURPAKAGE">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.YOURPAKAGE">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

NOTE:
Replace your AndroidManifest.xml file code with the above code and you just have to change the name of your package at those places where I have mentioned (YOURPAKAGE) hopefully the problem will be solved

Comment: This is actually the answer. Just not formatted very nicely. Nadir, please format.

Comment: MainActivity is not declared error requires manifest to include: activity with name and exported, and the intent filters nested in the activity. So many answers came close. Shame this one is buried for now.

Answer (score 0):

replace in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.justjava">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please edit your question and show us the main activity

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.stockquote.StockInfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             />
```

For more detail you can check here[Activity declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122386/activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for taking the time out to help a beginner. 
I found out that I had somehow misspelled the Package in MainActivity.java
When I corrected it the error was gone. 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error "The activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml", even though it was correct in the manifest file.

My problem was that when I created the project I had to mark the item "Use AndroidX artifacts".

Comment: This answer is outdated. In 3.6.1, Androidx is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you see that error occur after upgrading versions of IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio, or after Generating a new APK, you may need to refresh the IDE's cache.

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on my project suddenly my laptop restarts i tried lot of methods but i was not able to fix it.
But at the end i did it
do these steps and let me know it is working or not?

```
1. File > Invalidate Cache and restart the the android studio
2. Build > Clean Project and then Rebuild project
3. Sync project with gradle files
```

if it is still showing you error try these steps

```
1. Create new activity
   Remember to clink on checkBox Launcher Activity
   Hope this will Fix your problem
```

In the end go to AndroidManifest.xml and change New activity Default to previous activity

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the answers helped. Luckily, I remembered that I added a variable in build.gradle, which I tried to access from MainActivity.

Problem was that this new variable wasn't present in AndroidManifest.xml. Once I added the variable to AndroidManifest.xml, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd one. For me I had to open `Edit Configurations` (run configuration) and select `<no module>` under the Module drop-down. Then reselect my project under the Module drop-down and Apply. It the built and ran just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a project which I just downloaded the starter code for
an app , everything looked fine in the AndroidManifest.xml , I just deleted the **com.example.android.(yourappname).MainActivity** and wrote **.dMainActivity** and it worked.