# Unknown attributes in xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I mean the android attributes like width, height, id and ... .
I did everything:

1. Invalidate cache
2. clean & rebuild project
3. delete .idea folder

and all the other answers that we're suggested. None worked for me.
What did work was downgrading the sdk version from 27 to 26.
Any clues what might have happened to my 27 sdk version?

Edit:
[Unknown attribute ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggCAy.png)

```
2018-10-09 12:48:40.066 31822-31822/? E/Zygote: v2
2018-10-09 12:48:40.066 31822-31822/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10317
2018-10-09 12:48:40.066 31822-31822/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
2018-10-09 12:48:40.068 31822-31822/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
2018-10-09 12:48:40.068 31822-31822/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0010, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
2018-10-09 12:48:40.070 31822-31822/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.erfan.simplewebview 
2018-10-09 12:48:40.075 31822-31822/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2018-10-09 12:48:40.144 31822-31829/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
2018-10-09 12:48:40.144 31822-31829/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
2018-10-09 12:48:40.144 31822-31829/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
2018-10-09 12:48:40.489 31822-31822/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2018-10-09 12:48:40.628 31822-31822/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2018-10-09 12:48:40.844 31822-31822/? I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 69.0.3497.100 (code 349710002)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<uJ>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/TracingController;
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName!(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:400)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:349)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:194)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2325)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2320)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2379)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:4331)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:4473)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:579)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:627)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:572)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:555)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:542)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:652)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:724)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:792)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:734)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:865)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.053 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:873)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:873)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:873)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:525)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:427)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:378)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:139)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void com.example.erfan.simplewebview.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:93)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6956)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2927)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3045)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1642)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6776)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.TracingController" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName!(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:400)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:349)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:194)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2325)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2320)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2379)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:4331)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:4473)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:579)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:627)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:572)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:555)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:542)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:652)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:724)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:792)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:734)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:865)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:873)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:873)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:873)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:525)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:427)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:378)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:139)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void com.example.erfan.simplewebview.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:93)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6956)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2927)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3045)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1642)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6776)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.054 31822-31822/? I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.164 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 5 ms (timestamps 7402-7407)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.181 31822-31881/com.example.erfan.simplewebview E/cr_VariationsUtils: Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.example.erfan.simplewebview/app_webview/variations_seed_new": /data/user/0/com.example.erfan.simplewebview/app_webview/variations_seed_new (No such file or directory)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.241 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(36)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
2018-10-09 12:48:41.242 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "69.0.3497.100", actual native library version number "69.0.3497.100"
2018-10-09 12:48:41.302 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
2018-10-09 12:48:41.313 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f1204c5 (t=17 e=1221) (error -2147483647)
2018-10-09 12:48:41.420 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview I/chromium: [INFO:aw_field_trial_creator.cc(54)] First-WebView-Experiment not found
2018-10-09 12:48:41.514 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/Choreographer: init sf_choreo_doframe   debug_Level : 0x4f4cdebug_game_running : false
2018-10-09 12:48:41.639 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2018-10-09 12:48:41.661 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2018-10-09 12:48:41.666 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2018-10-09 12:48:41.671 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2018-10-09 12:48:41.973 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2018-10-09 12:48:41.983 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2018-10-09 12:48:41.993 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2018-10-09 12:48:42.022 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2018-10-09 12:48:42.022 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2018-10-09 12:48:42.090 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/ViewRootImpl@aabbaad[MainActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
2018-10-09 12:48:42.100 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=100
2018-10-09 12:48:42.100 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/ViewRootImpl@aabbaad[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@ccd61e2[MainActivity] touchMode=true
2018-10-09 12:48:42.164 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/ViewRootImpl@aabbaad[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2018-10-09 12:48:42.189 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/ViewRootImpl@aabbaad[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true -372262912} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
2018-10-09 12:48:42.189 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/ViewRootImpl@aabbaad[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true -372262912} hwInitialized=true
2018-10-09 12:48:42.208 31822-31987/com.example.erfan.simplewebview I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2018-10-09 12:48:42.208 31822-31987/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2018-10-09 12:48:42.225 31822-31987/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
2018-10-09 12:48:42.335 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
2018-10-09 12:48:42.362 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2018-10-09 12:48:42.373 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2018-10-09 12:48:42.380 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2018-10-09 12:48:42.394 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2018-10-09 12:48:42.472 31822-31822/com.example.erfan.simplewebview D/ViewRootImpl@aabbaad[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 81 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 81 - 0, 0) or=1
2018-10-09 12:48:42.494 31822-32024/com.example.erfan.simplewebview W/cr_CrashFileManager: /data/user/0/com.example.erfan.simplewebview/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory
```

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
      compileSdkVersion 27
      defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.erfan.simplewebview"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      }
      buildTypes {
        release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
      }
    }

    dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
      implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
      implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
      implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
      implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
      testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
      androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
      androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
      implementation 'com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1'
      implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
      implementation 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.8.0'
    }
```

Comment: provide **Logcat** error.

Comment: You might have different SDK versions for support libraries.

Comment: Maybe you have to install components of 27 from SDK Manager

Comment: Sorry I'm new here and I don't know to put the logcat in a scrolling view and I don't any crashes so I don't know if the logcat helps.

Comment: @ErfanEstiri Hello erfan and welcome to SO. Would you add your `build.gradle` dependencies too? Yes that helps.

Comment: @ReazMurshed no all of them are the same version 27.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The codes and warnings you see are in runtime of the application. Stop the installation-run app then check your dependencies to see if there is a problem with them or not.

(Make `compileSdkVersion` & `targetSdkVersion` the same version to 27) If you're using 27 support libraries.

However, your layout doesn't seem to be fine.

Move `layout_behavior` to your `NestedScrollView` or `RelativeLayout` (or actually, the content below the `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: I added the build.gradle but it was added to the end of the logcat. As u can see both compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion are 27. I also moved the layout_behavior and no changes. I don't see any code completion since they're unknown.

Comment: Stop the app installation. Then reinvalidate-cashes restart. This should help. Also, in your layout there were few issues which I’ve explained.

Comment: A lot of problems are occurring after updating AS to 3.2v.

Comment: It’s acutally might happens because of AndroidX migration or the new support library 28.0.0. You can also use 28.0.0 to see if those errors gone. Reinvalidate caches might help too.

Comment: Reinvalidating the caches didn't work until I deleted my sdk and downloaded it again. Now the previous issue is fixed but something new has occured.

Comment: Posted a new answer including both problems' screenshots.

Comment: Remove it (tools:context..) and it will work fine. About that java issue, it seems like it couldn’t find some java libraries - annotiotions. Use attach annotioations.

Comment: Won't removing that cause in problems in terms of connecting the xml layout to the java class? And also the attach annotations doesn't seem to do anything and the popup won't go away.

Comment: You won’t need that tools:context. However, check this link for that anothet issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740240/no-idea-annotations-attached-to-the-jdk-1-8-c-some-issues-will-not-be-fo

Comment: Thanks @Mohsen for putting the time. The second answer in the link provided seemed to make that popup go away but I still think I need to reinstall AS and downgrade to 3.1.2 since 3.2 seems really buggy. +1rep.

Comment: If you want to use support libraries yes, Android studio v3.2 is better for AndroidX migration. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not your sdk version

Add this in your build.Gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

your Exception is

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<uJ>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/TracingController;
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.TracingController" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

or post your code too. for better help.