# No IDEA annotations attached to the JDK 1.8 (C:\…), some issues will not be found

Tags: android, gradle, invalidation

I am also encountering this issue on the 3.2.1 version. If I change the Gradle version and invalidate the cache, it works.

for more details 
I just found the solution. Follow the directory in Android Studio IDE:

[image]

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No IDEA annotations attached to the JDK 1.8 (C:\...), some issues will not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740240/no-idea-annotations-attached-to-the-jdk-1-8-c-some-issues-will-not-be-fo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know my solution is late but I have recently experienced the same problem and was unable to find out any solution. Because of this issue, grade files were changing unexpectedly and I was unable to run any project. 
Solution: Download JDK from oracle's website(link is given) and install.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html