# Android Studio | Unable to run newly created project(s)

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, intellij-14

Since recieving the latest update from Android Studio (AS), my project was no longer able to run. After dealing with a few of the 30+ IDE errors I found manually cloning the entire project to be more efficient.

Though, when I create a new empty project it is not able to run due to the following error:

```
Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
```

So I tried the 2nd and 3rd suggestion offered by this thread:

[Error: Default Activity Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found)

But this made no difference.

Then I have reinstalled Android Studio, but unfortunatly without any improving results.

So now when I want to run any newly created project, it tells me it cannot find a registered activity. As one can see in the image, the activity is registered in the manifest.

I am hoping for new things I can try so I can finally move on with my work.

[image: Manifest and error]

Comment: try `file` -> `invalidate cache and restart`

Comment: First thing I have done, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it fixed by following the instructions of this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52829860/4895256

> What worked for me is to remove (or you can move it as a backup) the
>   ".AndroidStudio3.2" (for you it will be .AndroidStudio3.1) folder
>   located in "C:\Users{username}\" and then reopen the Android Studio.
>
> While launching I selected to import settings from the last version
>   and proceed. it will reconfigure all the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Build -> clean project then rebuild project.

Comment: Been there, done that. This issue unfortunatly goes a little deeper

Comment: 1: create new layout "NewActivity"
2: replace  .MainActivity to .NewActivity

Comment: Didn't do the trick either, the settings have been too messed up somehow