# Android Studio shows continuous error with plugins and androidAnnotations.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, ide

I don't know why, but Android Studio 3.2.1 display a plugin error continuosly. The error is always related to androidAnnotations.jar, like this:

```
Android Studio/plugins/android/lib/androidAnnotations.jar!/android/content/annotations.xml: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

I've updated to latest version of IDE and SDK but the error hasn't been solved. I tried to invalidate caches, reload the project from repository and resync gradle, disable and enable plugins, etc., but without success.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test and searchs on internet I've found how to solve this issue. Deleting some cache folders from .android, AS recreates it and problems are gone. I followed the steps from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740240/no-idea-annotations-attached-to-the-jdk-1-8-c-some-issues-will-not-be-fo) posted by @Levi Rizki Saputra.