# Some missing layout attributes in the textView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm looking for some attributes such as layoutCenteringParent in my textView and cannot find them. I want to find that specific attribute in order to center the text (I'm following an online tutorial). I tried to follow the advice here:
[Missing attributes in the layout design - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843163/missing-attributes-in-the-layout-design-android-studio)

and deleted my Android studio cache but it didn't help.
I'm a beginner so there is a good chance I'm just missing something here. I'm attaching a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Where do you want your TextView to be positioned ?

Comment: please click on Infer constraints icon on top. Looks like magic stick.

Comment: let me know my answer worked for you or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ConstraintLayout you should **constrain** `Textview` from all four sides to center it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ABC"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use `ConstraintLayout`, like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greeting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is an excellent tutorial about `ConstraintLayout`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4N4bCdyGcUc

Answer (score 1):

To center text's container set all constraints as parent and remove any biases.
To center text inside container use android:gravity = "center"