# my layout folder get red lines after migrating Android Studio from 3.6.2 to 4.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

This is kinda weird

I just recently migrated my android studio from 3.6.2 to the latest version because of some need. When I reopen a project that was build from 3.6.2 there's suddenly red lines on the layout folder like this

[image]

The problem is , when I tried to run the project it will build and run successfully without any error. And there's no way to know what or why it got marked as error. This is kind of annoying, anyone know how to remove those red lines?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting Android Studio without caches.

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart
```

If that doesn't work try cleaning them manually. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54846190/2408342).

Comment: Can you open the files which are underlined red and check code to see whats wrong?