# ConstraintLayout seems not work in module and chaos

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

the code and preview in an anroid module

[image: code preview]

the same code in main

[image: same code in main]

I have tried to delete the build folder of module and rebuild the project, but couldn't work

Comment: What exactly you want

Answer (score 0):

when I solve another problem，it works.

> No IDEA annotations attached to the JDK 1.8 (C:\…), some issues will
>   not be found
>   [No IDEA annotations attached to the JDK 1.8 (C:\...), some issues will not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740240/no-idea-annotations-attached-to-the-jdk-1-8-c-some-issues-will-not-be-fo)