# Installing app debug but not able to open

Tags: android, android-manifest

Here is my android manifest file.  I can install the apk, but I cannot open it.  How do I allow it to open?

`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/lockicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"



    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

`

Comment: please share full code & maybe you got the log error that you can share it?

Comment: Please share your error/exception.

Answer (score 0):

No **Activity** is registered in your manifest file. Register your activities in manifest and also initialize launcher screen. For more read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I can't find how to do this in android studio, i can only find how to initialize my activity in eclipse

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122386/activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml