# Crashes on StartActivitity() Android Apps

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting the error "*Unable to start activity ComponentInfo*".

When I call **start_salud** function:

```
public void start_salud(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, salud.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

It crashes on `startActivity(intent)`

I call it from `android:onClick="start_salud"` .

**salud_class:**

```
package com.alertavecino.alertavecino;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class salud extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> listDiseases;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.salud_layout);
    }
}
```

**Dubbing results:**

```
        if (mResolvedMethod == null) {       // <-- This statment is true
            resolveMethod(mHostView.getContext(), mMethodName);
        }

        try {
            mResolvedMethod.invoke(mResolvedContext, v);    // <-- Here it's crashes
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Could not execute non-public method for android:onClick", e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Could not execute method for android:onClick", e);
        }
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alertavecino.alertavecino">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Alerta Vecino!"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Cat Log:**

*11-25 20:17:31.924 29226-29226/com.alertavecino.alertavecino E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
11-25 20:17:31.924 29226-29226/com.alertavecino.alertavecino E/Zygote: v2
11-25 20:17:31.944 29226-29226/com.alertavecino.alertavecino E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL*

Comment: Post the crash log please

Comment: could you post your manifest?. Suspect.

Comment: It's likely that you haven't declared the activity in your manifest. Add the entire error from the logcat, and your manifest.xml to the question.

Comment: That's not your whole log. There's no error there. Change the report level to error, and remove any filters you have on your logcat.

Comment: Done, what do you mean by declaring the activity in the manifest?

Comment: Let's continue this in chat.
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129076/crashes-on-startactivitity-android-apps

Comment: Thanks a lot, post it as an answer and I will check it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your activity in the manifest in order for it to be able to be started.

Add the following to your manifest.xml file inside the `<application>` tags:

```
<activity android:name=".salud">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This will allow your activity to be started, and also make the activity launchable from the device app list.

Answer (score 0):

You must to register all activities in your manifest, you could do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alertavecino.alertavecino">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Alerta Vecino!"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".salud" >
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

check also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122386/activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml) and [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)