# Android apk install failed Not found Activity

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, apk

`Android Version: 7.0 (Nougat)`

Hi,

I'm beginner developers on mobile in Android. I had a problem on 04.21. This problem is `‘Not found Activity’` and I need help in understanding it.

I'm experiencing the issue by following this flow:

1. New Project ‘A’ created in Android Studio;
2. Build a project and run the app on an Android device (`Galaxy Note5`, `Galaxy Note4`, etc.);
3. Verify the app is running successfully;
4. Remove the app from the device;
5. Find `app-debug.apk` file in project directory (e.g.: `A/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`);
6. I’m move the `.apk` file from Notebook to device and install the `.apk` on the device using: `adb install app-debug.apk`
7. Check the app's complete installation on the device;
8. App crashes due to `NotFound MainActivity.java files` error, found in the log.

I've found a quick fix to my issue, by adding the following:

```
jackOptions, gradle 
    jackOptions {
     enabled true
    }
```

But now, I have no idea why the above snipped in fixing my problem. Can someone please help me debug this issue, or find a workaround to my problem?

Thanks!

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: How did you made your .apk file?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122386/activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity Declaration in AndroidManifest.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122386/activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml)

Comment: @AbdulKawee Just run project then find apk on outputs/apk/.apk file

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: may be error is because of you are making .apk in the wrong way

Comment: @Beginner Developer Please try to add full path to your activity. For ex. You package name is com.example then in your manifest file you give full path to your activity com.example.MainActivity then try it works for me.

Comment: If were you known other ways that make apk file please tell me

Comment: @BeginnerDeveloper checkl the answer below, it has the procedure of generating apk

Comment: @BeginnerDeveloper do tell me if it helps you\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> GoTo>>Build>>Generate Signed APK

Now you will have a form like this
[image]

Click on Create new, and create key store for your apk
[image]

Fill out the form as in the picture. And use these credentials to generate signed .apk[image]

Like this, Hope it solves your problem, Follow the [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Generating_a_Signed_Release_APK_File_in_Android_Studio) if you want to know the more details

Comment: Sorry.. Generate Signed APK failed install and a little different answer flow    just moment please  :)

Comment: @BeginnerDeveloper yeah sure , share the details

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the manifest file and define your main Activity.

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: sorry, already added to code. This project is New Project I'm not modified

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a problem. Are you sure the adb installation has been successful? Maybe you need to pack the release version,the debug version can run directly ,and the installation may need to be signed.