# declaring an activity in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

[image]

I started yesterday with developing app on Android Studio and I am not sure how to declare my activity in AndroidManifest. I read the post on [Activity Declaration in AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122386/activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml) but I am still not sure what to put for the name and label and how to find their exact names. I would really appreciate your help and thank you.

Comment: Add your manifest file here.

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

Read doc about Manifest file [Manifest file structure](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.brianballz.a1ibsos">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

       <activity android:name=".CreateAccountActivity"></activity>
       <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! May I know what I did wrong in my codes? So my problem was that there was an activity inside intent tag? How about my app name and label like was there a problem there?

Comment: you forgot this line in your code <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Comment: Okay I understand now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @JeonghwanLee Thanks, Happy to help you.

Comment: Just 1 more thing but I can set set an activity as a starting default using AndroidManifest right? There are 2 things currently on my Manifest which is CreateAccountActivity and LoginActivity but when I run the app, it does not show those 2 things but the original template. I tried deleting the origina acitivty.xml and debugging the app but it didnt work so what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As per your shared image you have added activity inside of intent tag. Please out it from intent-filter tag. 
Please check below code also. Might be it will help.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.product.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
           //second activity
            <activity android:name="com.product.activities.MainActivity" />

        </activity>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I already got a solution from Ratial.

Comment: Just 1 more thing but I can set set an activity as a starting default using AndroidManifest right? There are 2 things currently on my Manifest which is CreateAccountActivity and LoginActivity but when I run the app, it does not show those 2 things but the original template. I tried deleting the origina acitivty.xml and debugging the app but it didnt work so what should I do