# How to code for Grid Layout onClickListerner

Tags: java, android, gridview, onclick, onclicklistener

While coding for Grid Layout onClickListerner.. There's error coming in the log report  of

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.ViewGroup.getChildAt(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.lenovo.skanda.HomeFragment.setSingleEvent0(HomeFragment.java:42)
        at com.example.lenovo.skanda.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:31)

**HomeFragment.java**

```
package com.example.lenovo.skanda;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    GridLayout mainGrid;
    View viewroot;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        viewroot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

        mainGrid = (GridLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);

        setSingleEvent0(mainGrid);
        setSingleEvent1(mainGrid);
        setSingleEvent2(mainGrid);
        setSingleEvent3(mainGrid);
        setSingleEvent4(mainGrid);
        setSingleEvent5(mainGrid);

        return viewroot;
    }

    private void setSingleEvent0(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        CardView cardView = (CardView)mainGrid.getChildAt(0);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Its CEO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setSingleEvent1(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        CardView cardView = (CardView)mainGrid.getChildAt(1);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Its CTO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setSingleEvent2(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        CardView cardView = (CardView)mainGrid.getChildAt(2);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Its Accounts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setSingleEvent3(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        CardView cardView = (CardView)mainGrid.getChildAt(3);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Its Receptionist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setSingleEvent4(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        CardView cardView = (CardView)mainGrid.getChildAt(4);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Its Chief Architecture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setSingleEvent5(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        CardView cardView = (CardView)mainGrid.getChildAt(5);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Its Chief Accountant", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:background="#fdbbed">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textGrid"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="11dp"
            android:text="“Believe in yourself! Have faith in your abilities! Without a humble but reasonable confidence in your own powers you cannot be successful or happy.”"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="#affa86"
            app:cardElevation="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/cardview1"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/symptoms_image"
                    android:src="@drawable/sucide1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="SUCIDE AND CAUSES"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="#85f557"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="48dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/Stories_image"
                    android:src="@drawable/script"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="SURVIVOR TALES"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="#111"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="48dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/Positivity_image"
                    android:src="@drawable/meditation"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="POSITIVITY AND MOTIVATION"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="#111"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="48dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/Chatwithus_image"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/quotes"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="QUOTES"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="#111"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="48dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/Faq_image"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_chat1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="CHAT WITH US"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="#111"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="48dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/Aboutus_image"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_aboutus"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="ABOUT US"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".OnBoardActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Registration">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".fragment_quotes" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Stories" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Feedback">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving any code that references your views to onViewCreated, not onCreateView. Specifically, this portion :

```
mainGrid = (GridLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);

    setSingleEvent0(mainGrid);
    setSingleEvent1(mainGrid);
    setSingleEvent2(mainGrid);
    setSingleEvent3(mainGrid);
    setSingleEvent4(mainGrid);
    setSingleEvent5(mainGrid);
```

Comment: I don't understand. Will you please elaborate.!!

Comment: your code is in the onCreateView method, which runs before your views are created - therefore attempting to access them will throw an exception. You must override the [onViewCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated) method and put your code in there, since this method runs after the views have been created. Hope this is clearer

Comment: I have done that, but after then there's error flashing on screen in the log:



Process: com.example.lenovo.skanda, PID: 8794
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.lenovo.skanda/com.example.lenovo.skanda.ChatFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @itzPrateek As the error says you should define your activity in manifest. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122386/activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml

Comment: @itzPrateek instead of calling (GridLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainGrid) try to call (GridLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.mainGrid) in your onViewCreated() method. where view is an input parameter. Your grid view is a part of your fragment, not the host activity.

Comment: About this error "ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class". It seems that you're trying to start your fragment in intent without the host activity, or your host activity is not defined in the manifest. Could you please provide your code where you try to start this fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Move your codes form `onCreateView` to `onViewCreated` :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainGrid = (GridLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);
    setSingleEvent0(mainGrid);
    setSingleEvent1(mainGrid);
    setSingleEvent2(mainGrid);
    setSingleEvent3(mainGrid);
    setSingleEvent4(mainGrid);
    setSingleEvent5(mainGrid);
}
```

Comment: After implementing this... 
It's not working on fragments classes. It's works only on AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Ok Done but a error is poping up in log after clicking on cardview on grid layout.

Error ::               
Process: com.example.lenovo.skanda, PID: 9819
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.lenovo.skanda/com.example.lenovo.skanda.PositivityFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?