# Adding Main Activity to Manifest: element is not allowed here

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

When I run my code, I get the error: "The activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml"
I added a few lines of code in manifest based on what I've been seeing online, but now I am getting these errors. How would I fix this?

I've tried exiting manifest and syncing with gradle files but it did not work
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zLgl.png)

Comment: `activity` tag should be inside of `application` tag., currently it's not. Take a look at this answer how it should be [activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122386/activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Your activity is outside the application tag  update it    remove   />   from application   replace it with  >  ... here add your activity

[image]